# How can I start a chat in Yahoo! Messenger?

Tags: yahoo-messenger

Here is a screenshot of my Yahoo! Messenger (I'm using v10). I don't see an option for starting a chat in the menu. Where is it?

[image: Messenger menu of Yahoo! Messenger v10]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question isn't quite clear about what functionality you are trying to find.

Are you trying to send a message to a single user? If so, that can be done through the "Send an Instant Message" option in the "Actions" menu.

Are you trying to open up a room in order to chat with multiple people? You can do that by using the "Invite to Conference" option in the "Actions" menu.

**EDIT**

Aha! Well, I have the option, and a quick web search shows me that [chat rooms are not available depending on country](http://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100210012423AAtc2AN).

The consensus on the web seems to be that you need to uninstall your current version and download the US version. Not sure if this helps you or not.

Comment: Are there no chat rooms then?  http://messenger.yahoo.com/features/chatrooms   "Chat rooms are a great place to meet and communicate with friends who share your interests. You'll find chat rooms for a world of topics from entertainment to sports, to politics and pop culture. Liven up your chats with emoticons, custom fonts and even voice...Chat rooms are available in Yahoo! Messenger 8.1, 9.0, 10 and Mac. To enter a chat room, look for "Yahoo! Chat" in your Messenger menu. Then select the topic you want to discuss to join an already active room full of chatters."

Comment: updated answer based on this new info

Comment: some or all rooms are flooded with bots.. probably not a good chat thing but wanted to see it! that solves it